# why "jar.enabled = false" affects dependencies in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, multi-project

The story:
I have recently discovered that setting `jar.enabled = false` in project b-features of a multi-projects Gradle project will stop project a-features of the same project from being able to refer to B via

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':b-features')
}
```

The question: 
Why is `jar.enabled = false` stopping project A from successfully referring to project B?

Additional info:

build.gradle of the root project:

```
group 'gradle.studies'
apply plugin: 'java'
...
```

settings.gradle of the root project:

```
rootProject.name = 'multi-project-reference'
include 'a-features'
include 'b-features'
```

build.gradle of the project `a-features`:

```
group 'gradle.studies'
apply plugin: 'java'
...
dependencies {
    compile project(':b-features')
}
...
```

build.gradle of the project `b-features`

```
group 'gradle.studies'   
apply plugin: 'java'    
jar.enabled = false    
...
```

Class A in `a-features` project:

```
package outerproject;

import innerproject.B;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(b.getMsg());
    }
}
```

Class B in `b-features` project:

```
package innerproject;
public class B {

    public B() {
        this.msg = "Hello World";
    }

    private String msg;

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }
    //...
}
```

**The error:**

```
14:27:50: Executing external task 'build'...
:compileJava NO-SOURCE :processResources NO-SOURCE :classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE :assemble UP-TO-DATE :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
:processTestResources NO-SOURCE :testClasses UP-TO-DATE :test
NO-SOURCE :check UP-TO-DATE :build UP-TO-DATE :b-features:compileJava
UP-TO-DATE :b-features:processResources NO-SOURCE :b-features:classes
UP-TO-DATE :b-features:jar SKIPPED
/home/nikita/IdeaProjects/multi-project-reference/a-features/src/main/java/outerproject/A.java:3:
error: package innerproject does not exist import innerproject.B;
                   ^ /home/nikita/IdeaProjects/multi-project-reference/a-features/src/main/java/outerproject/A.java:7:
error: cannot find symbol
        B b = new B();
        ^   symbol:   class B   location: class A /home/nikita/IdeaProjects/multi-project-reference/a-features/src/main/java/outerproject/A.java:7:
error: cannot find symbol
        B b = new B();
                  ^   symbol:   class B   location: class A 3 errors :a-features:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you actually depend on, is the artifact (JAR file) that is produced by the project. As you disabled the generation of the artifact (`jar` task), the needed classes of course are not found any longer.